# Remove blank lines in div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a tag:

```
<pre>
     this is a

    this is b


       this is c
</pre>
```

After parsed by browser, it outputs:

```
     this is a

    this is b


       this is c
```

What I want is:

```
this is a
this is b
this is c
```

Is there any way to **only use client methods** to do this?

Change `<pre>` tag to `<div>`? But it turns to single line, not I want.

Add css? I did not find a style to achieve.

Or use javascript?

**PS**: the content in `<pre>` tag is generated by liquid template `{{ post.content}}` , it is **immutable**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Trim and filter out empty lines.

```js
// get the pre tag
var pre = document.querySelector('pre');

pre.innerHTML = pre.innerHTML
  // split by new line
  .split('\n')
  // iterate and trim out
  .map(function(v) {
    return v.trim()
    // filter out non-empty string
  }).filter(function(v) {
    return v != '';
    // join using newline char
  }).join('\n')
```

```html
<pre>
     this is a

    this is b


       this is c
</pre>
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using `pre tag` which mean preformatted text, anything included between this tag whether it's `space` or `line-break`, the output will be same as included.

> The HTML  element represents preformatted text. Text within this
>   element is typically displayed in a non-proportional ("monospace")
>   font exactly as it is laid out in the file. Whitespace inside this
>   element is displayed as typed.

So you could make use of some other tag, still you could remove space between those sentences using `JavaScript` as added by Pranav C Balan

```html
<pre>
  
  Hi xyz demo text.Hi xyz demo text.
  
          Hi xyz demo text.
  
  Hi xyz demo text. 
</pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

dont use "pre" tag. use simple

```
<div>this is a</div>
<div>this is b</div>
<div>this is c</div>
```

i hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

```
<p>
 this is a<br/>
 this is b<br/>
 this is c<br/>
</p>
```

with HTML, you can do this!
Pre tag in HTML prints as it is without a word-wrap and with whitespace in tact.