# Css flex display with resize chops of background

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a simple code snippet block (editable) but I can't seem to get it re-sizable properly

"Best" solution so far

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
<style>
    .program {
        background-color: #282c34;
        color: #ABB2BF;
        outline: none;
        padding-left: 8px;
        white-space: nowrap;
        display:inline-block;
        width: 100%;
    }
    .wrap {
        font-family: "Courier New";
        flex-direction: row;
        display: flex;
        resize: vertical;
        overflow: auto;
    }
    .numbers {
        background-color: rgba(50, 50, 50);
        color: rgb(200, 200, 200);
        font-size: 16px;
        padding-right: 16px;
        padding-left: 8px;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="wrap">
    <div class="numbers">
    1 <br/>
    2 <br/>
    3 <br/>
    4
    </div>
    <div class="program" contenteditable="plaintext-only">let a = new Array(10);
for (let i = 0; i &lt; 10; i+=1){
    a[i] = i;
}





</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/1y897ntg/

However this has the problem described in the title where when the wrap div is smaller than the text no back ground is drawn when scrolling to the side or bellow (zoom in and scroll) and additionally it doesn't scroll when newlines are added (resize than spam enter and than type "e")

What I want:
-when wrap is smaller than the program it scrollbars should appear
-the background should always cover the code view
-numbering should have a different color than the program
-only allow vertical resizing
-Pure Css (if possible)

Bonus:
-not able to resize smaller than program height
-set custom min height (example 4 lines) which overwrites the previous bonus

(I can't change the div structure only the css)

Comment: Why can’t you change the DOM?

Comment: DOM structure is the result of an external library (codejar)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The wrong background color is due to the fact that the color is not configured on the `.wrap` but on the `.program`

The code snippet block cannot be configured with a min-height because the white space is coming from your html as empty lines:

```
<div class="program" contenteditable="plaintext-only">let a = new Array(10);
for (let i = 0; i &lt; 10; i+=1){
    a[i] = i;
}





</div>
```

This can't be easily avoided without changing the html structure, but there's an example on how to do that via js [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42312515/remove-blank-lines-in-div).